# How to display same person have all colorcodes in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I have a question about SQL Server:

how to get which name have same color code or more when compare to colors table

All color codes from colors table match with name related colorcode then display that name

Examples:

- `persioncolores` table with `name = tom` has color codes `red,blue,green,brown`
- `Color` table has color codes: `Red,blue,green`

So all 3 color codes of `tom` are matched, then display his name

Here: color table related all color codes have for the name of tom  so we need to display this name

Similar to name of joe  also have all 3 color codes so we need to display  this name as output

Another name : Hari have only two matched colorcode  so no need to display his name

nani  have only 1 matched colorcode so no need to display his name

Test have no mathced colorcode so no need to display his name

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[colors]
(
    [colorcode] [VARCHAR](50) NULL
) 

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PersionColors]
(
    [Name] [VARCHAR](50) NULL,
    [ColorCode] [VARCHAR](50) NULL
) 


INSERT INTO [dbo].[colors] ([colorcode]) 
VALUES (N'Red'), (N'Blue'), (N'Green')
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[PersionColors] ([Name], [ColorCode]) 
VALUES (N'Tom', N'Red'), (N'Tom', N'Blue'), (N'Tom', N'Green'), (N'Tom', N'Brown')
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[PersionColors] ([Name], [ColorCode]) 
VALUES (N'Joe', N'Red'), (N'Joe', N'Blue'), (N'Joe', N'Green')
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[PersionColors] ([Name], [ColorCode]) 
VALUES (N'Hari', N'Red'), (N'Hari', N'Blue')
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[PersionColors] ([Name], [ColorCode])  
VALUES (N'Nani', N'Blue')
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[PersionColors] ([Name], [ColorCode]) 
VALUES (N'Test', N'Orange')
```

Based on above data I want output like this:

```
Name 
------
Tom
Joe
```

I tried this SQL:

```
select distinct 
    name, a.colorcode  
from  
    [dbo].[PersionColors] a  
join 
    colors b on a.ColorCode = b.colorcode
where 
    a.ColorCode = 'red' or a.colorcode = 'blue' or a.colorcode = 'green'
```

This query is not returning the expected result.

Can you please tell me how to achieve this task in SQL Server?

Comment: Let's suppose a table with Mary and Lola, Mary has yellow and green and Lola has blue and red. What names do you expect in output? Both? Why? It is about how has more different colors?